# Heroku(Ruby on Rails) unable to access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I was trying to move my just started ruby on rails website from local to public and I used Heroku for that.

All steps were fine except the last one which was:

- `git push heroku master` — to push my application to Heroku, but instead of generating files and giving me the link it ends up like this:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/glacial-gorge-31258.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
>     CAfile: `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
>     CApath: none

I'm sure that I made mistake somewhere, since I was half lost while installing and I can see that it has something to do with locations in my computer, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got once the same error for git

I have fixed it by following way.

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

or ignore checking

```
git config --system http.sslverify false
```

May be it might will help you

Comment: @ rajarshi Das Thank you, the second one helped. Thanks mate :)